# FQL - can't get link info from user - 'Request Failed' error

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

This should be an easy one.  All I want it the user's profile url.

I've tried the following FQL:

> SELECT profile_url FROM standard_user_info WHERE uid = me()

but get the `Request Failed` error.  I'm using the Graph API Explorer / FQL Query and have the latest Access Token.

Basically I'm looking for the FQL equivalent to this Graph API call:

> https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=link

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

If you read the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/standard_user_info/) properly, you'll notice that-

1. `standard_user_info` requires the `APP_ACCESS_TOKEN`, instead of `USER_ACCESS_TOKEN`. You can get the App Access Token from the [Access Token Tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/access_token/), for the testing.
2. You can get the information about the authorized app users only.

So, you can test it like this-

```
SELECT profile_url FROM standard_user_info WHERE uid = USER_ID
```

**Note**: Don't use `me()` (since you are using the app access token now which didn't recognize `me()`), instead use you `ID`)